# Desktop flexible grid amount of content in a row

Tags: flutter, flutter-widget, flutter-desktop, flutter-design

I have problem designing inside a flexible a grid where it can go from 3 item in a row on full screen to be 1 item in a row on the smallest allowed size of the application, is there a widget or guide for this?

Answer (score 2):

use ResponsiveGridList from the package https://pub.dev/packages/responsive_grid.
It is simple and well documented. I used once already, it fitted my needs perfectly.

Comment: It might be a great solution for my problem so first of all thanks, need to check license and everything before using it, it is well documented so thank you very much, but isn't it kind of weird there is no support natively in Flutter for this?
are we sure there isn't a way to do this otherwise?

Comment: this is not a suggest way.